# What’s the difference between using objects and functions for namespacing in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I saw these 2 basic ways of namespacing in JavaScript.

1. Using object:

   **`var Namespace = { };`**

   `Namespace.Class1 = function() { ... };`
2. Using function:

   **`function Namespace() { };`**

   `Namespace.Class1 = function() { ... };`

How do they differ? Thank you.

Comment: [Essential JS Design Patterns Book](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#detailnamespacing) contains a chapter about different namespacing patterns.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As others have pointed out, a function is an object so the two forms can be interchangeable. As a side note, jQuery utilizes the function-as-namespace approach in order to support invocation *and* namespacing (in case you're wondering who else does that sort of thing or why).

However with the function-as-namespace approach, there are reserved properties that should not be touched or are otherwise immutable:

```
function Namespace(){}

Namespace.name = "foo";  // does nothing, "name" is immutable
Namespace.length = 3;    // does nothing, "length" is immutable
Namespace.caller = "me"; // does nothing, "caller" is immutable

Namespace.call = "1-800-555-5555" // prob not a good idea, because...

// some user of your library tries to invoke the
// standard "call()" method available on functions...
Namespace.call(this, arg); // Boom, TypeError
```

These properties do not intersect with `Object` so the object-as-namespace approach will not have these behaviours.

Answer (score 6):

The first one declares a simple object while the second one declares a function. In JavaScript, functions are also objects, so there is almost no difference between the two except that in the second example you can call `Namespace()` as a function.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if **all** you're doing us using that "Namespace" thing as a way to "contain" other names, then those two approaches are pretty much exactly the same. A function instance is just an object, after all.

Now, generally one would use a function like that if the function itself were to be used as a constructor, or as a "focal point" for a library (as is the case with jQuery).

Answer (score 3):

They don't. Functions are "[first class objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)". All this means is that conceptually and internally they are stored and used in the same ways. Casablanca's point of one difference you can call it as a function is a good one though. You can also test for whether or not the class was defined through a function with the `typeof` operator.

```
typeof {}
```

returns "object"

```
typeof (function())
```

returns "function"