# Difference between javascript object and function

Tags: javascript

object 1:

```
var vehicle = {
        name : "car",
        wheels : 4,
        fuel : "petrol"  
}
```

object 2:

```
var vehicle = function(){
    this.name = "car",
    this.wheels = 4,
    this.fuel = "petrol"   
}
```

When both of the objects describe the object `vehicle` in the same way, what is the difference between them?

Comment: All functions in JavaScript are objects and can be used to create objects.

Comment: Duplicate question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125479/what-s-the-difference-between-using-objects-and-functions-for-namespacing-in-jav

Comment: Side note: Those commas in the second example should be semicolons. The code *works*, because of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), but in general using commas instead of semicolons is poor practice and can bite you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When both of the objects describe the object vehicle in the same way, what is the difference between them?

They don't. Your first `vehicle` is an object; `vehicle.wheels` is `4`. Your second `vehicle` is a **function** (also an object, but that's not really relevant here); `vehicle.wheels` is `undefined` because that function doesn't have a `wheels` property. You'd have to use `var v = new vehicle();` and then `v.wheels`.

Use object initializers (your first example) when you need a one-off object. Use a function (like your second example) if you need a *factory* for objects that have the same shape.

Note that *if* your factory is a *constructor* function (a function that expects to be called with `new`, such as your `vehicle` function), it should be initially capitalized by (overwhelming) convention.

But your factory doesn't have to be a constructor function, it could be a function that just returns an object, in which case you woulnd't use it with `new`, wouldn't use `this` inside it, and wouldn't typically capitalize it. E.g.:

```
var vehicle = function(){
    return {
        name: "car",
        wheels: 4,
        fuel: "petrol"   
    };
}
```

(It could use `Object.create` if it wanted to assign the object a specific prototype.) Whether you use that and `var v = vehicle();` or a constructor function and `var v = new Vehicle();` is mostly a matter of style.

Answer (score 1):

The object in JavaScript refers to any entity or a data element. Whereas, a function is a procedure to be performed to achieve something. A function may or may not return an object.

In this case, it looks confusing as they both are used for the same purpose. But, generally this is not how a function is used.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new instance of this function/class.

```
var vehicle = function(){
    this.name = "car",
    this.wheels = 4,
    this.fuel = "petrol"   
}

Function/Class Objects can be instanciated.

var v1 = new vehicle(); //Here v1 is an instance of vehicle
console.log(v1.name); // Car
```

In this case you can not create a new instance of this Object. It's just an Object.

```
var vehicle = {
        name : "car",
        wheels : 4,
        fuel : "petrol"  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Amrinder is right. With the first example you create an object

```
var vehicle = 
{
    name : "car",
    wheels : 4,
    fuel : "petrol"  
}
//vehicle.name shows "car"
```

If you use option 2 you create a function which you can call to create an object with the given values:

```
var vehicle2 = function()
{
        this.name = "car",
        this.wheels = 4,
        this.fuel = "petrol"   
}
var vehicle = new vehicle2(); 
//vehicle.name shows "car"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Object --> has property
2. function --> return some value/object do some manuplication with Objects

> ```
> var vehicle = 
> {
>     name : "car",
>     wheels : 4,
>     fuel : "petrol"  
> }
> typeOf(vehicle) // returns "Object"
>
> var vehicle = function(){
>     this.name = "car",
>     this.wheels = 4,
>     this.fuel = "petrol"   
> }
> typeof(vehicle) // output "function"
> ```