# How to use 'Function.prototype.call' to invoke a function that is not attached to prototype of any object

Tags: javascript

The output of the following code is `undefined has undefined wheels` instead of `Bike has 2 wheels`. 
Is it not possible for an `Instantiated object` to call the function which is not attached to the `prototype` of any object?

```js
var vehicle = function(name, wheels){
 name = "car",
 wheels = 4,
 fuel = "petrol"
}

function drive(name, wheels) {
 console.log(this.name + " has " + this.wheels + " wheels" );
}

var vehicle1 = new vehicle('Bike' , 2);
drive.call(vehicle1); //undefined is driven with undefined wheels
```

Comment: Inside the `vehicle` function you need to define those variable using `this....`, for example: `this.name = "car"`.

Comment: Your vehicle constructor should do `this.name = ...` to attach the variable to the instance. You're just declaring implicit globals.

Comment: Still I get , `car has 4 wheels`

Comment: @Prem Have you not seen T.J. Crowder answer?, you have more than one error..

Comment: I have made corrections as per @T.J. Crowder. But it logs as `car has 4 wheels` instead of `Bike has 2 wheels`

Comment: @Prem did you fix your constructor function so that it obeys the passed parameters instead of hard-coding "car" and 4?

Comment: @Prem: Clearly, you haven't. Please read [Pointy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46564847/157247) and [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46564863/157247) **carefully**.

Comment: Yes. @Pointy & T.J Crowder's comments & answers resolved the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, almost everything about your code is incorrect.

First, the "vehicle" function must set properties on `this`, and it should use the passed-in parameters instead of constants:

```
var vehicle = function(name, wheels) {
    this.name = name,
    this.wheels = wheels,
    this.fuel = "petrol"
}
```

Then, your function "drive" should take no parameters at all:

```
function drive() {
  console.log(this.name + " is driven with " + this.wheels + " wheels" );
}
```

To call `drive()` with your vehicle as the `this` value:

```
var vehicle1 = new vehicle("Bike", 2);
drive.call(vehicle1);
```

The first parameter to `.call()` will be used as the value of `this` inside the called function.

Answer (score 3):

Several issues:

1. You're using `vehicle` as a constructor function, but not assigning any properties to `this`.
2. You're not using the `name` or `wheels` parameters in `vehicle`
3. You're defining `name` and `wheels` parameters to `drive` but not using them and not supplying them when calling it.
4. Not really an *issue*, just convention (as I mentioned on [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46563659/difference-between-javascript-object-and-function)): If you're going to use `new` with `vehicle`, it should be initially capped: `Vehicle` by *overwhelming* convention.

See comments:

```js
var vehicle = function(name, wheels){
  // Actually use name and wheels and put them on `this`
  this.name = name;
  this.wheels = wheels;
}; // <== Added missing ;

function drive(/* No parameters here*/) {
 console.log(this.name + " is driven with " + this.wheels + " wheels" );
}

var vehicle1 = new vehicle('Bike' , 2);
drive.call(vehicle1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `this` like this:

```js
var vehicle = function(name, wheels){
 this.name = "car",
 this.wheels = 4,
 this.fuel = "petrol"
}

function drive(name, wheels) {
 console.log(this.name + " is driven with " + this.wheels + " wheels" );
}

var vehicle1 = new vehicle('Bike' , 2);
drive.call(vehicle1); //undefined is driven with undefined wheels
```